# Why does this transition from $B$ to $B'$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

This question is related to the question [Transition matrix which rotates counter clockwise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2872580/transition-matrix-which-rotates-counter-clockwise) (don't panic, I'll get around to approving the answer soon).

The text now says that if the vector sets
$$
   B=\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n \} \\
  B'=\{u_1, u_2, ..., u_n \} 
$$
are bases and if
$$
  v_1 = c_{11}u_1 + c_{21}u_2 + ... + c_{n1}u_n \\
  v_2 = c_{12}u_1 + c_{22}u_2 + ... + c_{n2}u_n \\
    \vdots
  v_n = c_{1n}u_1 + c_{2n}u_2 + ... + c_{nn}u_n
$$
then the transition matrix 
$$ Q = 
\begin{bmatrix}
  c_{11} & c_{12} & ... & c_{1n} \\ 
  c_{21} & c_{22} & ... & c_{2n} \\ 
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
  c_{n1} & c_{n2} & ... & c_{nn} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is called the transition matrix from $B$ to $B'$. The proof is rather algebraic and not very enlightening, but isn't that name backwards?

(Also, is there a tag for embarrassing questions?)

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand what is meant by "transition matrix."  What it means it that if you have a vector $X$ expressed in terms of basis $B,$ then to get the representation in terms of $B'$ you multiply by $Q.$

To convince yourself of this, suppose $$X=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\dots+a_nv_n.$$

To express $X$ in terms of $B'$ you just have to substitute the expressions for the $v_k$ into the expression for $X$ and collect like terms.  Let's just concentrate on $u_1$.  What will be the coefficient of $u_1$ in the expression for $X$?  Well, from $v_1$ we'll get $a_1c_{11},$ from $v_2$ we'll get $a_2c_{12},$ in general, from $v_k$ we'll get $a_kc_{1k}.$  Altogether, we get the first element of 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  c_{11} & c_{12} & ... & c_{1n} \\ 
  c_{21} & c_{22} & ... & c_{2n} \\ 
    \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\
  c_{n1} & c_{n2} & ... & c_{nn} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1\\
a_2\\
\vdots\\
a_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and a similar argument works for the other elements of course.  This is what the proof in your book is doing, but it's probably a good deal more compact.  Try to read it again now.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have a vector $x$ in coordinates $(x_i)$ regarding $B$ 
$$
x = \sum_i x_i v_i
$$
what coordinates $(x_i')$ would it have regarding $B'$?
$$
x = \sum_i x_i' u_i
$$
We already know what coordinates the basis vectors $v_i$ of $B$ have regarding $B'$, they form the matrix $Q^\top$:
$$
v_j = \sum_i c_{ij} u_i 
$$
So
$$
x 
= \sum_j x_j v_j
= \sum_j x_j \sum_i c_{ij} u_i
= \sum_i \sum_j c_{ij} x_j u_i
$$
which means
$$
x_i' = \sum_j c_{ij} x_j \iff \\
(x') = Q (x)
$$
So $Q$ transforms a vector of coordinates regarding $B$ into a vector of coordinates regarding $B'$, designating the same vector.